# testing a webapplication using jUnit or some other api?

Tags: java, ajax, testing, web-applications, junit

I am wondering if its possible to create a testing suite for testing a web application using junit API?
or we have to add other APIs, or is there any other better option?

Will this support ajax, jquery, javascript?

I mean will I be able to test the web application that uses javascript, ajax, jquery?

Comment: Better is a matter of opinion. Try Google for web test frameworks, checking candidates for a list of features, and downloading and using? This will give you your own opinion on 'best'. Factors to consider are popularity, active forum, active developers.

Comment: Yes is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the possible solutions for you ( http://java-source.net/open-source/web-testing-tools)